# multiply selected column in matrix with a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to multiply selected column with a group of vector.

Example:

```
[0 1 1

0 1 2

0 1 3]
```

As matrix above, I want to multiply column 3 with a vector [1; 2; 3]. Can anyone please help me to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to compute the dot product between these two vectors, or do you want to do a point-by-point multiplication?  It's not quite clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the result of your multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do **point-by-point** multiplication.  As such, you can simply take your vector (let's call it `v`, where `v = [1; 2; 3];`) and multiply this with the third column of your matrix (let's call the matrix `A`) by:

```
out = A(:,3) .* v;
```

By this way, this is very basic MATLAB syntax.  Suggest you read tutorials before you ask any further questions here.

Comment: I did as you mentioned but I think I got problem with the loop.

Comment: @NadiahZ - Your question does not involve a loop, so I don't know what you're referring to

Answer (score 0):

Let A be the matrix. To get the n-th column (left-most is column #1), you can do

```
    A(:,n)
```

Assuming you want the **dot product** of the given vector and the 3rd column, you can compute

```
    A(:,3)' * [1; 2; 3]
```

or

```
    sum(A(:,3) .* [1; 2; 3])
```

Comment: Oh, I just edited my second one to compute the dot product, which is what I thought he wanted. After rereading the question, I guess it doesn't specify which type of product he wants (dot product or element-wise).

Comment: I agree.  I'm not sure which one the OP is asking for!